# ckeditor line break using <p>

Tags: html, css, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor and it breaks new line by using `<p>`.

[image: ckeditor]

But I want to output to html using bootstrap. It doesn't line break on image.

[image: screenshot of page]

And I tried to use `<br>` and ckeditor replaced it with `<p>`.

How can write css for images within `<p>` tag to be line break?

Comment: I tried to use br tag and ckeditor replace it with p tag. How can i write css for images inside p tag to be line break?

Comment: Try giving image display:block;

Comment: it is not working

Comment: Add your snippet here for better understanding of what's happening...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.block {
  padding-top: 20px;
  display: block;
}
p {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/k18JpK/images_20.jpg">
</div>
```

Please check the above code, If you take block property its come in block form otherwise you have to take this 
 tag in HTML for breaking the line.

Answer (score 0):

Run this snippet and see the result I hope it helps you in your problem.

```css
img{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<p>this is some text here<img src="#" alt="myimage">
</p>
```